# Laravel5 MongoDB query builder with jenssegers not working

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I'am using MongoDB in my laravel 5 application using  [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#installation). I configure every thing in my project when i call my controller its show error.

Error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2057:
Call to undefined method Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::getAfterFilters()
```

config/app.php:

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
```

bootstrap/app.php.

```
$app->register('Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider');
```

database:

```
'default' => 'mongodb',

'mongodb' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mongodb',
    'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'options' => array(
        'db' => 'admin' 
    )
),
```

Please help ,where i missing some configuration.